# Format number in a Table Cell

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm constructing a Word doc from VBA (Excel) with Excel table data. The data was placed in the table is OK. The last column has the figure (e.g. 4900000).I want the  number-format to be (e.g. 4,900,000)

```
 If (iPrevNumMonths = iNumMonths) And bNewTemplateOpened = False Then
        'Insert New Row
        Set objTbl = iDoc.Tables(iDoc.Tables.Count - 1)
        objTbl.Rows.Add
        tRow = objTbl.Rows.Count
        sLoanAcctNum = Trim(ish.Range(zbookCol("<<lan>>") & lr).Text)
        objTbl.Cell(tRow, 1).Range.Text = sLoanAcctNum
        objTbl.Cell(tRow, 1).Range.Font.Bold = True
        objTbl.Cell(tRow, 2).Range.Text = "MUR " & ish.Range(zbookCol("<<sl>>") & lr)
        objTbl.Cell(tRow, 2).Range.Font.Bold = True
        objTbl.Cell(tRow, 3).Range.Text = ish.Range(zbookCol("<<mn>>") & lr) & " Months (up to " & sMorDate & " ) - Moratorium on " & ish.Range(zbookCol("<<mor>>") & lr)
        objTbl.Cell(tRow, 3).Range.Font.Bold = True
        objTbl.Cell(tRow, 3).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 0
        objTbl.Cell(tRow, 4).Range.Text = "MUR " & ish.Range(zbookCol("<<emi>>") & lr) & "/-"
        objTbl.Cell(tRow, 4).Range.Font.Bold = True
        objTbl.Cell(tRow, 5).Range.Text = ish.Range(zbookCol("<<pmd>>") & lr)
        objTbl.Cell(tRow, 5).Range.Font.Bold = True
    Else
```

sl is the figure (4900000)

Comment: You can use `Format()`

Comment: i have used objTbl.Cell(tRow, 2).Range.Text = "MUR " & ish.Range(zbookCol("<<sl>>") & lr) & Format(strCellValue, "#,##0"). It's not working

Comment: `objTbl.Cell(tRow, 5).NumberFormat = "#,##0"`  the LAST colunn, is that not column 5 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how your data are formatted, that could be as simple as:

```
objTbl.Cell(tRow, 2).Range.Text = "MUR " & ish.Range(zbookCol("<<sl>>") & lr).Text
```

Otherwise, try:

```
objTbl.Cell(tRow, 2).Range.Text = "MUR " & Format(ish.Range(zbookCol("<<sl>>") & lr),"#,##0")
```